# linq strange error with null

Tags: linq, null

i have function

```
public List<Menu> List(int? parentId)
        {          
            return (from i in _dataContext.Menu where i.Menu2.Id == parentId select i).ToList();

        }
```

if i pass in function parameter null (like List(null)) it search nothing, but if i put null in query like this

`return (from i in _dataContext.Menu where i.Menu2.Id == null select i).ToList();` it finds records

what the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to filter out with the linq query?

Comment: i have a table T with fields id, parentid, name. i make relationship with own table so parentid=>id one to many, so if parentid=null it is a parent record, and if parentid not null it is child record. so i whant get all parents

Comment: could you give some more code where you use the List function?

Comment: Also, what is the type of i.Menu2.Id

Comment: id int primary key, parentid int nullable, name varchar. i call func List from controller 
public ActionResult MenuList(int? parentId)
        {
          return View(_dataManager.Menu.List(parentId));            
        }

and MenuList can be called without parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm in the debugger that you are actually passing in null and not 0.